# Need to convert a datetime.tzinfo *region* to a ZoneInfo region

Tags: python, datetime, python-dateutil, zoneinfo

I'm writing a calendar application, and I have been trying to track down why canceled / rescheduled calendar entries keep appearing on my calendar. I traced the problem to a time zone issue with rruleset.

Let's say that I have a recurring weekly event and I'm in the US Eastern time zone. They're all scheduled at noon, but the recurrence overlaps the shift on November 5th from EDT / GMT-4 to EST / GMT-5.

If I do this:

```
 dtstart = datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 22, 12, 0, 0).astimezone()
 dtend = datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 12, 12, 0, 0).astimezone()
 instances = rrule.rruleset()
 instances.rrule(rrule.rrule(freq=2, dtstart=dtstart, interval=1, wkst=1, until=dtend))
 print(dtstart.tzinfo)
 for i in instances:
     print(i)
```

...I get four dates, but they're all pegged to EDT, because that's when dtstart begins:

```
 EDT
 2023-10-22 12:00:00-04:00
 2023-10-29 12:00:00-04:00
 2023-11-05 12:00:00-04:00
 2023-11-12 12:00:00-04:00
```

But if I do this:

```
 dtstart = datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 22, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('US/Eastern'))
 dtend = datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 12, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('US/Eastern'))
 instances = rrule.rruleset()
 instances.rrule(rrule.rrule(freq=2, dtstart=dtstart, interval=1, wkst=1, until=dtend))
 for i in instances:
     print(i)
```

...then I get the correctly shifted times:

```
 2023-10-22 12:00:00-04:00
 2023-10-29 12:00:00-04:00
 2023-11-05 12:00:00-05:00
 2023-11-12 12:00:00-05:00
```

So it appears that all I need to do is to take a datetime and extract the datetime.tzinfo *zone* (i.e., US/Eastern) and use it to create a zoneinfo.ZoneInfo object. I'm finding it impossible to do that: ZoneInfo can't figure out the region from the tzname of 'EDT'. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your example should be a [mcve] with imports so people that want to help you can just cut/paste/run your code.  FYI, `EDT` isn't supported timezone in `zoneinfo.available_timezones()`, but `EST5EDT` is (may need to `pip install tzdata` on some OSes).  Does that help?

Comment: `EDT` isn't a timezone name, not in `ZoneInfo` or anywhere else.  It's just a common nickname.  You can create a dictionary to convert those nicknames to actual timezone names.

Comment: `.astimezone()` is returning a default fixed time zone offset (e.g., `datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=61200), 'Pacific Daylight Time')`), instead of a DST-aware time.  `rrule` is using the time zone of the datetime passed into `rrule.rrule`.  That's why using a correct DST-aware timezone like `US/Eastern` or `EST5EDT` works.

Comment: Note: EDT and similar names are not unique. Is EDT, for you, the (Australian) Eastern Daylight Time? -- And do not confuse time zones with time offsets. EDT (and similar) are time offset: a timezome may have two of them (daylight and winter time)